# Adding multiple sublayers to UIView will only display one

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer

Trying to add a bottom border to my login system, I have used the following code:

```
var bottomBorder = CALayer()
bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, userEmailAddressTextField.frame.size.height - 1, userEmailAddressTextField.frame.size.width, 1.0)
bottomBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
userEmailAddressTextField.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)
```

I am trying to do this to my password textfield as well. I have used a various amount of techniques but none seem to work.

**First attempt:** Adding the same code again, this only shows the bottom border for the second bar.

**Second attempt:** I tried the same thing with a different variable being bottomBordertwo and then replicating code, but that wouldn't work either. Any solutions?

Comment: is ur textField is an IBoutlet or programmatically created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a common function

```
func addBottomLayerToTheView(view:UIView)
{
    var bottomBorder = CALayer()
    bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, view.frame.size.height - 1, view.frame.size.width, 1.0)
    bottomBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    view.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)
}
```

call this function after creating textFields or any other views that need bottom layer like:

In `viewDidLoad()`

*`addBottomLayerToTheView(textField)`*

*`addBottomLayerToTheView(textField2)`*

*`addBottomLayerToTheView(anyView)`*